# why Connection test failed?

Tags: mysql, node.js, strapi, react-fullstack

When i select custom setting and select sql and enter all fields
Connection test failed: Cannot find module\AppData\Local\Temp\strapi9a2b8146f759\node_modules\strapi-connector-bookshelf\lib\utils\connectivity.js'

Answer (score 1):

I know It's old but I just want to reply for future people who have the same issue.
Try to use `yarn create strapi-app --quickstart` or using npx `npx create-strapi-starter --quickstart`, and It'll use the default template
and then when It finish getting dependencies and finish setting up your project go to a file called `database.js` and add your database set of infos.
Got this info from issue opened in github : [Here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3758)